# Weird behavior when using contact form in Azure App Service to send email through SendGrid

Tags: azure-web-app-service, sendgrid, azure-custom-domain

I have a contact form on my website hosted on Azure App Service, used to send emails through SendGrid. It works well when I use the website with the default Azure URL ***.azurewebsites.net, but I does not work when I use the custom domain attached to the Azure App Service.

Any idea if it could come from SendGrid configuration?

Thank you.

Comment: Sending email with SendGrid utilizes an [API key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email#how-to-send-an-email), which isn't tied to the domain of your app service. What error messages are getting emails are sent from your custom domain?

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Answer (score 0):

When you use custom domain in web app, you need to set up domain authentication in sendgrid.

[1. How to set up domain authentication](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication/)

[2. Configure SendGrid in Microsoft Azure for email campaigns and smtp relay](https://ezcloudinfo.com/2019/11/06/configure-sendgrid-in-microsoft-azure-for-email-campaigns-and-smtp-relay/)

After valied your custom domain, your issue will be solved.